# Set the right crs on sf object to plot coordinate points

Tags: r, gis, geospatial, map-projections, r-sf

I'm trying to define the right CRS for my `sf` object. I want to plot points atop the following layer (country: the Netherlands):

```
Simple feature collection with 380 features and 3 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 13565.4 ymin: 306846.2 xmax: 278026.1 ymax: 619232.6
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    +proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs
```

output:

[image]

This layer has the correct projection.

But the `POINT` layer doesn't have the correct CRS project presumably because it has no `proj4string`?

```
Simple feature collection with 566 features and 5 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 3.5837 ymin: 50.86487 xmax: 7.120998 ymax: 53.44835
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
```

[image]

How do I set the same projection as the previous map so I can plot the coordinates points on it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In addition, there is the function `st_set_crs()`, which can be used in a pipe. For example,

`points %>% st_set_crs(st_crs(polygons))`

Comment: I couldn't find a function `st_set_crs` in package `sf`. Is this outdated now?

Comment: It seems it's part of the [``geotidy``](https://etiennebr.github.io/geotidy/reference/crs.html) package.

Comment: `sf::st_set_crs()` exists.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`st_crs`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/sf.pdf#page.54).

As it says in the examples:

```
st_crs(x) <- value
```

In your case it would probably be

```
st_crs(points) <- st_crs(polygons)
```

*Note:* the points should be registered in the same coordinate system, of course. If not, you would have to find out the correct coordinate system for them and then use `st_transform` to put them into the same coordinate system as the polygons.