# How to clipe a .tif based on each polygon stored in a shapefile?

Tags: r, raster, spatial, r-raster, rgdal

I have access to a tif file which contains satellite images of the Netherlands (e.g.  https://ns_hwh.fundaments.nl/hwh-ortho/2022/Ortho/1/01/beelden_tif_tegels/2022_079000_449000_RGB_hrl.tif),
and a shapefile containing the plot area (parcel area) of houses.

```
area <- readOGR( 
  dsn = paste0( getwd(), "/Perseel/" ) , 
  layer = "Essellanden_percelen",
  verbose = F )

plot(area)
```

The .shp file looks like the following:
[image: Plot area]

My end goal is to output each polygon of the plot area separately as an image (.jpg or .png) to be able to use them in image recognition, but I don't know how to get there.

The first step would be to overlay the plot areas on top of the satellite image, such as:
[image: Example map]

Next step would be to cut out the plot areas one by one and output them as .jpg.

I read the data into R as a RasterBrick (.tif) and SpatialPolygonsDataFrame (.shp) and tried to convert either to be of the same data type so it would be easier to lay on top of each other, but I was unable to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your tif raster is georeferenced, you can use `raster::crop` to cut the image to the extent of each of the polygons in your shapefile by looping over it.

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)

lapply(seq_len(nrow(area)) function(i) crop(aerial_image, extent(area[i,), snap="out")
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I tried your code and adjusted it as follows: 
```
loop <- function(i) {
  crop(image, extent(area[i,], snap = "out" ) )
}

lapply( seq_len ( nrow( area ) ), loop)
```

This is giving me an error: "Cannot get an Extent object from argument y". Running only "crop(image, extent(area[1,]))" gives the error that the extents do not overlap. Do you know how I can check the extent and make sure they are similar?

Comment: In addition the projection of area is: "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs". The projection of aerial_image is: "+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.1561605555556 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs"

Comment: @Maaike set the projections to be the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232331/set-the-right-crs-on-sf-object-to-plot-coordinate-points Moreover, no need to save the clip as a function. Use it as is in my answer, it will loop through your data. I am not sure what did you do with `loop` and why did you do it. After you set the projections, it should work. Based on your screenshot, the extents are matching.